# Confluent Connect on Different Port Not Working

Tags: confluent-platform, portainer, confluent-control-center

I'm setting up the Confluent-Stack using portainer on a Linux computer. One of my other containers is already using port 8083 (the default confluent-connect port) - so I replaced 8083 in the docker-compose.yml file with 8089. However, when everything starts up, I cannot see a connect cluster in the control center at all.

This is my base docker-compose.yml file:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/7.0.1-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml

I got this link from here:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html

I've spun up the stack in portainer (not using a docker-compose command as suggested in the above tutorial) using the .yml file edited a little to replace the "8083:8083" with "8089:8089" and replace other "8083" occurences with "8089".

I also initially used port 7777 as a replacement, in this case I though I should replace "8083:8083" with "7777:8083" and the other "8083"'s I replaced with "7777". I'm a little new to these ports and clearly not understanding how one is supposed to set this up?

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up being able to reroute the other container that was using the 8083 port without issues, so I could use the default docker-compose file for the confluent stack and then everything worked fine. So my problem is solved, but the issue may still haunt me.